# How to position image over another image and scroll it over background

Tags: reactjs, layout

I want to create a mobile application preview on a desktop browser using React. The preview should display an avatar-style image over a background image. When the user scrolls down the article, the article body should move over the background image, hiding it. An example of this layout can be viewed here: [imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/Glwj1kf).

How can I implement this overlapping image on the top layer?